# SQL where DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, time, mariadb, datediff

Hi guys i have table in mysql

[image]

I need filter results where created_at and updated at difference between those timestamps 2 hours or less

I'am trying to use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `imoniu_r_padaliniai`
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, created_at, updated_at) <= 2;
```

But i get syntax errot how achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use direct comparisons:

```
where updated_at <= created_at + interval 2 hour
```

In MySQL and MariaDB, `datediff()` only handles date differences.  If you want arbitrary time differences, you need `timestampdiff()`.  However, I recommend using direct comparisons instead.

The three-argument form of `datediff()` is the syntax in SQL Server (and a handful of other databases), not MySQL.